# How to make internal borders with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am doing a ring plot with `ggplot` and I would like to add borders to the categories but they overlap. Is there a way to make the borders internal to the rectangle?

Reproducible example. 
Data:

```
plot.df <- data.frame("number"=c(3455, 3714, 2345), 
                      "group"=c("A","B", "C"))
plot.df$fraction <- plot.df$number / sum(plot.df$number)
plot.df <- plot.df[order(plot.df$fraction), ]
plot.df$ymax <- cumsum(plot.df$fraction)
plot.df$ymin = c(0, head(plot.df$ymax, n=-1))
```

Plot:

```
ggplot(plot.df, aes(color = group, fill=group, 
                    ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, 
                    xmax=4, xmin=2.5)) +
  geom_rect(alpha = 0.6, size = 4) +
  coord_polar(theta="y")  +
  xlim(c(0, 4)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid=element_blank(), axis.text=element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.ticks=element_blank()) +
  labs(title="My Ring Plot", x = "", y = "", 
       fill = "", color = "") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

I get the following plot, that is correct except for the borders.

[image: ring plot]

For example, between B and C only the the B (green) border is visible and I would like to see a thick green line next to a thick blue line. Did I explain myself?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

I found a dirty solution, it is not perfect or elegant but it kind of does the job.

First we need to modify the ymin column

```
plot.df$ymin = c(0.0125, head(plot.df$ymax, n=-1)+ 0.0125)
```

and then add a new row for a "ghost" category

```
plot.df <- rbind(c(234, "D", 0.0125, 0.0125, 0), plot.df)
plot.df[,4] <- as.numeric(plot.df[,4])
plot.df[,5] <- as.numeric(plot.df[,5])
```

now we can make the plot hiding the "ghost" category

```
ggplot(plot.df, aes(color = group, fill=group,
                    ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin,
                    xmax=4, xmin=3)) +
  geom_rect(alpha = 0.6, size = 4) +
  coord_polar(theta="y")  +
  xlim(c(0, 4)) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("A", "B", "C"),
                    values = c("red", "green", "blue", "white"),
                    aesthetics = c("colour", "fill")) +
  theme(panel.grid=element_blank(), axis.text=element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.ticks=element_blank()) +
  labs(title="My Ring Plot", x = "", y = "",
       fill = "", color = "") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image: ring plot 2]

That looks like what I was looking for, but the way I made it is not ideal.

Any other solution to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: This is because of the sequence of plotting the different sections. C is plotted first, A plots over C and B plots last. This leads to A shadowing the line of C and B the line of A. You can easily see this if you just have a look to  `ggplot(plot.df, aes(color = group, fill=group, 
                    ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, 
                    xmax=4, xmin=2.5)) +
  geom_rect(alpha = 0.6, size = 4)` . I would find it anyhow better to have white lines between the sections.

Comment: this should not be possible. There is no "external" border. With the size parameter you control the border line size. So what happens is: you expand the line size of the border equally inside and outside. The reason why it overlaps is already explained well by @MarBlo

Comment: @MarBlo thanks for your comments. I know I can use thin (default size) borders and/or borders of the same color but I am trying to improve the appearance of the plot.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @mischva11, I modified my question since the borders are centered to the edges of the rectangle and increasing at the same time to both sides (inside and outside) as the size parameter increases.